# Touchpad does not work when returning from hibernation on 17.10

Tags: touchpad, 17.10

When the computer (lenovo yoga 900) comes back from hibernation; the touchpad doesn't work, I can't move the pointer.

I hope this info helps.

---

> Linux YOGA 4.13.0-16-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 11 18:35:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

---

```
$ xinput list

⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:13                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13
```

---

Hardware info:

```
mouse:
  /dev/input/mice      ELAN21EF:00 04F3:227C
  /dev/input/mice      Synaptics TM3066-002
```

Thanks

Comment: I noticed an issue today where two finger scrolling does not work after hibernate, on a Thinkpad X1 Carbon running Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 1):

On a Lenovo S440 after hibernation 2-finger scrolling and window resizing does not work when using Wayland. Only fix seems to be a restart.

**Solution**

On login choose 'Ubuntu Xorg' instead of 'Ubuntu'. When using the Xserver instead of Wayland it has my touchpad working after waking up from hibernation.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue - Razer blade stealth 7th gen intel

```
~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Waking up from suspend only keyboard works.
There is no HW button to try enable/disable the touch.

Comment: This is not an answer - consider adding a comment to the question instead.